# URL rewriting with TomCat

Tags: tomcat, rewrite

I am looking to rewrite an incoming url request on TomCat with the Tuckey rewriter:

```
<rule>
<from>/OutputFile?sourceArticleId=([0-9]+)</from>
<to>/app/clipping/get/$1</to>
</rule>
```

the "?" question mark fails the regexp pattern matching. How can I properly escape it or what is the correct solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I' m not too familiar with reg exp in urlrewrite but you can try:

```
<from>/OutputFile\?sourceArticleId=([0-9]+)</from>
```

In many languages, the escaping character is the `\`

**Update:**

According to the [doc](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html), by default, the query string is not included in the `<from>` element. So you can try with the `use-query-string` set in the `urlrewrite`

Also make sure that the `default-match-type` in the `<urlrewrite>` is set to `regex` (I use the Spring MVC template from STS and it is set to `wildcard` by default

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
<rule match-type="regex">
    <from>/OutputFile\?sourceArticleId=([0-9]+)</from>
    <to>/app/clipping/get/$1</to>
</rule>
...
```